# Fastlane Android:Gradle sync failed: Could not find method screengrabVersion() for arguments

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

**In Event Log,**

Gradle sync failed: Could not find method screengrabVersion() for arguments [/Users/adminuser/Desktop/MyProject/version.properties] on project ':screengrab-lib' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

**In Message Gradle Sync,**

Error:(5, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'screengrabVersion()'
Possible causes:

The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).

Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project

The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

And nothing happen when I Click on "Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project"

I am using Android Studio version 2.3.3. Please help me on it.

Answer (score 0):

After checking many hours I removed module dependency and put below Gradle dependency in App build.gradle file and It's working fine now,

```
 androidTestCompile("tools.fastlane:screengrab:1.0.3", {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```